# Ios Safari 3d model loading limit issue (cordova app)

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, webgl, blender

I ran my application for android. I had no problems, but when I ran my ios application, my 3d models with a total size exceeding 10 MB were not loaded. I found the reason. explained here: https://www.fngtps.com/2010/mobile-safari-image-resource-limit-workaround/

but I can't find the solution. I understand I have two options.
1- I need to reduce the size of my models.
2- or I have to extend the limits of the safari.

but I don't know how to reduce the size of these models.
The second option is already somewhat impossible.

> I made my models with blender. and in obj format

thanks in advance to everyone who helped

Comment: that answer you linked to is unrelated to your issue. Your question is about file size, that question is about unit size. Just a suggestion but can you use another format like glTF? 10MB is not that big.

Comment: sorry, wrong link :(  is true link : https://www.fngtps.com/2010/mobile-safari-image-resource-limit-workaround/ . there are some limits according to what is told here. another format is difficult. that means too much work

Comment: Well, [here's a 50meg model](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/threejs-littlest-tokyo.html) and at least for me it loads on iOS. I don't have an app to test but I tried posting it to myself in the slack app and set the slack app to use the in app browser and it worked. That suggests your issue is something else? That link is 9 years old.

Comment: What do you think might just be the reason ios doesn't work? small models are loaded and animation begins. problems happen when large models start to load. I can't find the solution.